# Why does David Grant hide when George & Jean showed up near his parents?

Tags: plot-explanation, nebraska

In [**Nebraska**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1821549/), David Grant is shown hiding himself

[image]

when George & Jean showed up near his parents.

[image]

Why he is hiding from them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because David and Ross stole the air compressor from a wrong neighborhood. And when they realized it (from a funny conversation between them and their parents), they went back to put it back in the barn. That's when George and Jean arrive and David and his brother obviously don't want to be noticed coming out of their barn as they have no business up there. So they hide.